# Filter through multiple properties in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, loops, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to filter through multiple properties in Angular. I am able to filter through one property easily by using `filter:{ title: searchString }` but when I try to use multiple properties... it doesn't seem to get any result at all.

What I need to do is:

If `John Wayne` is passed through.. it shows `John Wayne` but if only `John` or only `Wayne` is passed through... It still shows `John Wayne`. Similarly for `n w` since `John` ends with an `n` and `subTitle` starts with a `w`

My Code:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="searchString">

<div ng-repeat="arr in arr1 | filter:{ title: searchString, subTitle: searchString }"></div>

$scope.arr1 = [
    {title: 'John',subTitle:'Wayne'}
    {title: 'Barry'}
];
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller("ListCtrl", ["$scope",
  function($scope) {
$scope.arr1 = [
    {title: 'John',subTitle:'Wayne'},
    {title: 'Barry'}
];
  }
 
]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.7" data-semver="1.4.7" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.7/angular.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app='app'>
  <div ng-controller="ListCtrl">
   title:<input type="text" ng-model="criteria.title"> 
   subtitle:<input type="text" ng-model="criteria.subTitle"> <br>
    <div ng-repeat="arr in arr1 |  filter: criteria">{{arr}}</div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: the issue is there is only one input to type not two

Comment: if you need to filter through multiple properties you need the model for each of those, you cant achieve with one search box. if you use it will acts like free text search